# How to use broadcast variables such as list in flink streaming program?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to use some other broadcast  resources such as list or map  in the flatmap function or customer triggers, but I don’t find some api to satisfy.

I find the broadcast method, but it's return the datastream, and how can i convert it to list, and how can i get it in streamcontext?

I use Flink-1.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to Flink's [broadcast state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html), then this was only introduce with Flink 1.5.

If you are referring to `DataStream#broadcast()` which controls the partitioning of records, then this won't allow you to specify a broadcast state. You will have to implement that on your own by specifying a corresponding `CoFlatMapFunction`, for example.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i have a new question.I want to read redis resource before start of the flink program, but encountered the following error:redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.But works well in the rich function, is there some limits for read redis in flink?

Comment: Do you mean connecting to Redis from your machine where you run the Flink program? If you want to do this, then you should make sure that you can connect from this machine to the Redis cluster.